# Why can't I access my ESP3288 USB after detaching REPL from UART0?

Tags: python, serial-port, esp8266, uart, micropython

What I put into my otherwise mostly empty main function was basically:

`import uos`

`uos.dupterm(None, 1)`

I uploaded this code to my microcontroller and it stopped being able to connect to my computer. My aim was trying to connect to a Bluetooth module (ZS-040). Now I can't even connect to the microcontroller.

I was intending to make a serial connection to the Bluetooth module while keeping the UART0 bus separate for USB and REPL connection. Now, I am stranded, having done quite the opposite. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled the webrepl, try using it to connect & upload a new, blank 'main.py'.
https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/esp8266/tutorial/repl.html?highlight=webrepl
(this works on my ESP8266 after running dupterm(None, 1)). Failing that, re-flash the firmware to erase 'main.py' and re write the script to either issue dupterm manually at the start or to issue 'dupterm(UART(0, 115200), 1)' after some later event to re-attach the repl.